# Parallel.ForEach with Enumerable of KeyValuePairs?

Tags: c#, .net, collections, task-parallel-library

Am I using the wrong overload method of the Parallel ForEach?
When I am using a normal ForEach loop, I am able to get the current item, which is the correct type (KeyValuePair) as expected.

But when I am using the Parallel version, it seems that even when I hover over the current object in the loop and it appears to be the correct type, still I don't get the Value and Key properties.

Thanks in advance!

```
static void TestParallelForEachKeyValuePair(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Animal, string>> kvps)
    {
        foreach (var kvp in kvps)
        {
            var test = kvp.Key;
        }

        Parallel.ForEach(kvps, (kvp) =>
        {
            kvp.
        });
    }
```

[ForEach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROsLu.png)

[Parallel ForEach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5jAYK.png)

[Hovering the current item inside Parallel ForEach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60870.png)

Comment: [I can't reproduce this](https://i.imgur.com/GofefKw.png).

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed , thank you for your quick feedback. Good to know. Does it mean that there is a bug somewhere? So strange.

Comment: Um, I'm not sure. Maybe something is wrong with intellisense. What happens if you manually type `var test = kvp.Key;`? Does the compiler complain at all? Did you try restarting VS?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed , If I manually assign the variable as you suggested, it worked. However, the problem with intellisense was still there after restaring Visual Studio. 

When I copied the same code to another computer, it works as expected. No issues with intellisense.

Not a big issue then. I can live with this. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this test method is working but IntelliSense not showing "Key" and "Value"
(Windows forms).
So its IntelliSense problem.

```
    static void TestParallelForEachKeyValuePair()
    {
        List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> test = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();
        test.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(1, "test1"));
        test.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(2, "test2"));
        test.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(3, "test3"));


         Parallel.ForEach(test, (x) =>
         {
             MessageBox.Show(x.Key + "  " + x.Value);
         });
    }
```